# Slow WIFI on Dell Venue 11 Pro (New to linux)

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, debian

I recently installed Debian 12 XFCE on my Dell Tablet and I followed this solution from [this Ubuntu forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187204&page=9&p=13103443#post13103443), without doing the following modifications because I don't know how to do them:

> Also needed is to tell the ath6kl driver that it can support the chip with SDIO id 0271:0418. It is a line like:
>
> {SDIO_DEVICE(MANUFACTURER_CODE, (MANUFACTURER_ID_AR6004_BASE | 0x18))},
>
> you have to add to the struct "static const struct sdio_device_id ath6kl_sdio_devices[]" in the file sdio.c of the ath6kl driver so it will handle the device.

After following this solution, WIFI is working on my Tablet, but the download speed is so slow e.g. 240KB/s . On Windows, the download speed was at 1MB/s.
Any suggestions, on how to fix it?